# Angular 2 - How to update table in component when use search box?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table with which it initializes getting API data in the `ngOnInit()` method.

This table is accompanied by a filter (input text) in which it is associated with a function that calls an API method that makes the filter.

This is my component:

```
[..]
@Component({ ... })
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  datas:     Courier[] = [];

  constructor( private _dataService: DataService ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._dataService.getData()
      .then(data => {
        this.couriers = this.datas.concat(data);
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.error = false;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.error = true;
        this.isLoading = false;
      })
  }

  searchData(searchKey: string){
    this._dataService.getData(searchKey)
      .then(data => {
        this.couriers = this.datas.concat(data);
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.error = false;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.error = true;
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  }
```

The search method works because it shows me the corresponding data and shows it in the table.
The problem is that it does not cool the entire table with initial data; add the filtered results to the table.

This is my html:

```
<table #datatable id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody *ngFor="let data of datas">
      <tr>
        <td class="courier_id">{{ data.id }}</td>
        <td class="courier_name">{{ data.name }}</td>
        <td class="courier_last_name">{{ data.last_name }}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

The search method in my component append more `<tr>` instead of refresh `<tbody>`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `this.datas.concat(data);` which will concatenate two arrays instead or replacing the original

Answer (score 0):

First, tbody not supposed to duplicated, you can put *ngFor on tr.

Second, contat concatenate two arrays for example:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [4,5,6] 
arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2) // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

you should use push instead for example:

```
datas = []
data = [1,2,3]
data2 = [4,5,6]
datas.push(data);
datas.push(data2);// [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Good Luck!